# 128-bit Float in Go - Equivalent of C#'s "decimal" Type

Tags: go

Simple question: is there an equivalent of C#'s [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) type in the Go standard library?

I intend to use this type to interface with an OData API that returns decimals at some endpoints, and from what I read, `complex128` is not suitable for this behavior (the storage of it is different than that of floats)

Comment: Are you familiar with https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/ ?

Comment: @Adrian I took a look at it before, but somehow I manage to gloss over `Float`. Ugh. If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: The `math/big` package is out there and works as advertised but it is nothing like a replacement for the gcc `__float128` "native" type.  To use `Float` is a pain and it is not anywhere as fast as native types.  Still, it supports major precision.  If you need the precision, it will give it to you.  If you need speed, forget it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard library's `math/big` includes a [`Float` type](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float):

> A nonzero finite Float represents a multi-precision floating point number